# How do I make an application that provides wifi connection priority

Tags: c#, android, ios, wifi

How do I make an application that will give priority to the wifi connection on both android and ios, that is, give priority to the network I will choose among wifi networks and always connect to the first ten. Can you help?

Comment: No, but we can help on specific questions regarding problems you may encounter while building said app.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.